# Getting ts+react to see an optional prop w/ default as non-nullable in the component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I get a React component to a) allow a prop as optional and b) see it as non-null once in the component?

e.g. I have this simple component:

```
import React from 'react';

type props = {
  x?: number;
};

const defaultProps: props = {
  x: 0,
};

export default function Foo({ x }: props) {
  x++;
}

Foo.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

how do I make it so that `x`, in the component, is a non-nullable type so that I can cleanly write `x++`?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solution.

```
interface IProps {
    x?: number;
    z?: string;
}

const Foo: React.FC<IProps> = ({x = 0, ...rest}) => {
    x++;
    const {z, children} = rest;
    // Do whatever you need to do with the props, e.g.
    return<div>
        X prop: {x}
        Z prop: {z}
        Children: {children}
    </div>;
};


/// Example how to use `Foo`
class ExampleClassA extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return <>
            <Foo/>
            <Foo x={2}/>
            <Foo x={2} z={"Z value"}>
                Children here
            </Foo>
        </>
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately has the problem of either restricting the default assignments to `render()` or requiring duplicate code or a helper function if you're to use `this.props` anywhere outside of `render()`.  Trying to get it working with `defaultProps` specifically, but thanks :)

Comment: I thought your question was about how to set default props for a functional component (like in your example), but not for a class component. So, you want to declare an object `defaultProps` and use it across multiple React components? Is this the problem you're trying to solve? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Well it applies to multiple cases.  For a functional component this is fine, so I'll probably accept it and re-ask ;)  But for a normal class component this would force duplicated code in any method in that component that uses `props`.

Basically I'm just trying to figure out how to write `<component>` + `defaultProps = {x: 42}` + `method() { x++; }` so that typescript is happy and doesn't complain about `x` being possibly `null`